# FTPS client, preferably integrated in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, ftp

I like Nautilus for FTP/WebDAV, but how to use it with an FTPS server?

When I enter `ftps://` Nautilus says `Don't recognize this file server type`.

Is there any plugin?
Or something as quick and convenient as Nautilus, with FTPS support?

gFTP from Ubuntu's repo says `FTPS Support unavailable since SSL support was not compiled in`.

---

*Note from Wikipedia: FTPS should not be confused with the SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP), an incompatible secure file transfer subsystem for the Secure Shell (SSH) protocol. It is also different from Secure FTP, the practice of tunneling FTP through an SSH connection.*

Comment: I didn't manage yet to get ftps support in gvfs (and since  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS doesn't list it as supported protocol, I didn't invest much time). For this reason, I'm using Filezilla as ftps client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

Nautilus supports FTPS now that the bug linked below has (finally) been fixed (Thanks @[HullCityFan852](https://askubuntu.com/users/350292/hullcityfan852)).

### Original post:

Nautilus does not support FTPS, see that [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=526582) (opened a long time ago but still no progress)

As an alternative, you can use FileZilla:

> FileZilla client supports FTPS both implicit (FTPS:// protocol), and
>   explicit (FTPES://).

[Source](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTPS_using_Explicit_SSL/TLS_howto_%28Server%29)

Comment: For anyone else wondering whether Nemo (Linux Mint's fork of Nautilus) supports FTPS as well: It does. The "Connect to server" UI doesn't allow to select FTPS, but if you enter a location manually using the FTPS protocol prefix like this "ftps://SERVER/PATH" it does in fact work and connect via FTPS. That's also true if the server supports regular FTP as well, so it doesn't just go the lazy route.

Comment: To be a little more specific: Input `ftps:username@serverurl` in the address bar of Nautilus. Adding the port after a colon does not seem to work. E.g.: `ftps://john@example.com@ftp.box.com`.

Comment: Filezilla being able to bookmark client and host folders, and having an MC-like pair of panes is good for me.  Plus if these are Azure deployment credentials, the strings are not short.

Answer (score 0):

Old discussion but maybe current still. It seems Nautilus does not do implicit tls but only explicit. Meaning with url like ftps://host, it will start with clear ftp port 21 and try to AUTH TLS which, to my understanding, is explicit. Eg. Citrix Sharefile does not support explicit, but supports implicit and thus can not be used with Nautilus.
If Nautilus is meant to to do only explicit, should't it require ftpes scheme?

Comment: Answering to my self: From https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/schemes found out that implicit requires ftpis scheme. It works. So, maybe Nautilus and others could do better quides!